# how can we know that an Android Application is closed?

Tags: android, android-studio, filepath

> I am developing an Android Application to download an .mp3 file from
>   server. When downloading is finished the file will be stored in a
>   DIFFRENT EXTENSION  (.srt) . and when the user clicked on the play
>   button the file's EXTENSION will be changed back into .mp3 and play
>   And when the user exit's the Application the file will go back to the
>   (.srt) format.

Everything works Fine . But now if the user close the application without pressing BackKey the extension  will be the same.

my code is

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        File file  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp3"); // handler to your ZIP file
                        File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.srt");
                        // destination dir of your file
                        boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
                       System.exit(0);

                         }
                }).create().show();

    }
```

if the user not Exiting through the proper way the function inside the exit button not works.

Comment: you may call the function on method onStop();

Comment: or you can use a service to perform background task and start the service when your app comes in background

Comment: can suggest me a code ..

Comment: ok wait for sometime

Comment: *the user not Exiting through the proper way* you mean when app goes to background?

Comment: I think 'ondestroy()' and 'onStop()' can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new service from Android Studio File->New ->Service ->Service
then override the onStartCommand method like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
File file  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp3"); // handler to your ZIP file
File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.srt");
 // destination dir of your file
 boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
 MyService.this.stopService(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }
```

then you can start it from onstop method of your activity by this

```
protected void onStop(){
super.onStop();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
startService(intent);
}
```

or you can do the same in onStop method like this

```
protected void onStop(){
super.onStop();
File file  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp3"); // handler to your ZIP file
 File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.srt");
 // destination dir of your file
 boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
 }
```

Comment: @Android Developer Trainee which code you used the onStop or created a new service

Comment: created a new service ... and pasted the above code.. :)

Comment: actually my suggestion is to use the service since it runs in background because sometime when you performed a long task in onStop of activity so may be it stopped in the middle since another activity on front of it.

Comment: so how could i continue use when another app come front

Comment: i have created a new service and pasted the code you given. but when playing music if another app come in front it stops. How can i continue play music in background ?

Comment: simply  create a new service and copy the music playing code in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121412/discussion-between-umar-ata-and-android-developer-trainee).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do more research on the Android activity lifecycle here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

The Android system will automatically call certain lifecycle methods, such as when the user leaves your app without pressing your exit button. You will most likely want to change your file extension back to .srt in the onPause() or onStop() methods.

Once the user returns to the app, you can revert the extension back in the onRestart(), onStart() or onResume() methods.

Hope that helps (my first answer on the site)!

Answer (score 0):

The onDestroy() method should be called when the application is terminated.