# My Service Gets Called On Emulator But Not Real Device

Tags: android

When I run my app in an emulator and kill the process, my service gets started and runs in the background (Toast: "Service Called") BUT it does not get called at all on a real device and no logcat runs because the broadcast receiver or my service does not get called:

MainFest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <!-- Service -->

        <service android:name=".MyService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.MyService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Service -->
```

MainActivity:

```
               AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  //TODO your background code
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PushNotification.class);
                    startActivity(i);
               }
            });
```

PushNotification.class:

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Context context = this;

            if (!isMyServiceRunning()){

                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);         

                finish();

                }
            else
                {
                    finish();
                }

        }


        private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

        }
```

BootReceiver:

```
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
                }
            }
           }
```

MyService:

```
            public class MyService extends Service {

            Handler handler;

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
            // START YOUR TASKS
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Context context = this;

                Intent in = new Intent(context, FragmentMain.class);
                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                in.putExtra("valuerunInBG", "1");
                context.startActivity(in);;     

                //loop();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // STOP YOUR TASKS
        super.onDestroy();
        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your manifest as given below

```
<receiver
android:name=".BootReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
android:label="BootReceiver">
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I made a small change in it just given the priority by which it will start as early as possible
also change the code given below

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        // START YOUR TASKS
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Context context = this;

            Intent in = new Intent(context, FragmentMain.class);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            in.putExtra("valuerunInBG", "1");
            context.startActivity(in);;     

            //loop();

    return  START_STICKY; //THIS WILL RESTART YOUR SERVICE IF IT GETS STOPPED BY ANDROID OS DUE TO LOW MEMORY
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this modification, service also starts app in UI unlike on my emulator where service started app in background, any recommendations for service to start app in background (also, not minimized but in background where app does not appear as running)

Comment: in android you have two classes to run code one is activity which provides ui another is service which runs in background and may start activity on a particular condition

Comment: as per your code inside onstartcommand method of service it will start FragmentMain.class if it is declared in manifest as activity

Comment: learn more about service by visiting this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: not really, i use loop() to test and it works only on emulator

Comment: I discovered an issue which may have something to do with my problem, my service runs randomly on my phone, sometimes only on the 3rd launch of my app will the service only run other times it does not run at all, this random behavior is making it difficult to pin point the problem!

Comment: service will run every restart I also used the same code in my project but you may also start it from your mainactivity

Comment: service gets called every time app is closed when i placed codein MainFragment instead of my MainActivity (I think what happens is my MainActivity calls Fragment first before my service is called), also I am rewriting my service to check and call notification from MyService.class rather than having it call back my Fragment which checks notification, anyway I will let you know how that worked out

Comment: for push notifications you may use firebase . It offers full source code for it for free

Comment: actually it is not required to check whether your service is running or not.  you may simply need to  remove code of checking whether it is running or not

Comment: my service works perfect now from the description of my 3rd last comment from this one. (..calling service from FragmentActivity and rewriting MyService.class to include the pushNotification and not call it from a separate class), service now runs in background (app does not appear under running) and I receive notifications even though app is closed just like how WhatsApp works.

Comment: oh by the way, I only checked whether my service is running or not for debugging, i removed the checking code once I was guaranteed that it is running

Comment: its my pleasure dear

Answer (score 0):

android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED Takes time after your device starts, try waiting 3-4 minutes

Comment: The service is called after I restart the phone but not when I close the app

Comment: to call a service when app is closed have a look on my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050860/how-can-we-know-that-an-android-application-is-closed/39050975#39050975

Comment: Go with this tutorial i also needed same thing and this tutorial helped me

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-make-android-service-unstoppable.html

Answer (score 0):

**Start your service again** in your service class's `onDestroy()` method. This way when your application will be closed, then `onDestroy()` will be called and that will start your service again.

Comment: Ok this answer helped a bit, unlike on my emulator, calling my service again on onDestroy calls my app to UI everytime I close it instead of running service in the background

Comment: what do you mean by UI everytime?

Comment: on emulator I managed to only get a toast message while the app does not start I can still get notifications if I simulate a message from my database however on real device the app loads up and starts as if a user clicked on the icon

Comment: Just start service in service class on destroy method not activity

Answer (score 0):

Some time Toast does not work inside of Service so please use Log to know whether your code is running or not.